# Having an issue with a flyout menu on Tablet

Tags: tablet, menubar, flyout

I have a website to be viewed on tablet. It's meant to fit to the screen. There is a flyout menu, the slides out from the left side. This menu is long, so it's scrollable. It's meant to scroll while the rest of the page remains the same. My issue is that sometimes when I use my finger to scroll the menu, it works fine, but there are times when I scroll and it drags the entire webpage down where the browser background appears towards the top. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Please supply more information.  Check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes - I have a website to be viewed on tablet. It's meant to fit to the screen. There is a flyout menu, the slides out from the left side. This menu is long, so it's scrollable. It's meant to scroll while the rest of the page remains the same.   My issue is that sometimes when I use my finger to scroll the menu, it works fine, but there are times when I scroll and it drags the entire webpage down where the browser background appears towards the top. Is there anyway to fix this?